# Mounting compressed filesystem using FUSE

Tags: mount, compression, btrfs, fuse

I'd like to move some folders on my computer to a compressed read/write images, so I could get it to take less disk space on my machine (the folders contain some Mercurial and Git repositories). Because I am not using these repositories daily, I'd prefer to have mounting them manually using FUSE.

So far, I've found how to create an empty btrfs filesystem:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/empty bs=1 count=0 seek=100M
mkfs.btrfs /tmp/empty
```

How do I mount this folder? When I type `$ fusermount /tmp/empty` I get `fusermount: old style mounting not supported`.

Comment: Hello from the future. Just wanted to point out that git archives are already compressed so you will not have gained much space.

Answer (score 1):

https://code.google.com/p/fusecompress/wiki/Usage

looks like you may need to get another package to do that fusecompress is the command listed here.